# Prove that the Lexicographical Order is Partially Ordered

Tags: set-theory

> Let $X$ be a partially ordered set under $\le$. Let $FIN(X)$ be the set of finite sequences (including the empty sequence) whose members are elements of $X$. 
>   If $\sigma = (x_1 x_2 ... x_n)$, $\tau = (y_1 y_2 ... y_m) \in X$, we say $\sigma \le_L \tau$ if and only if either $\tau$ extends $\sigma$ or where $j$ is least so $x_j \ne y_j$ then $x_j \le y_j$.

By extension, we mean that there is a sequence $\rho \in X$ such that $\tau = (\sigma$ followed by $\rho)$.  So, let $X = \{0, 1\}$, with $0 \le 1$.  If $\sigma = (100)$, $\rho = (110)$, then $\tau = (\sigma$ followed by $\rho)$ = $(100100)$.

1. The part "where $j$ is least so $x_j \ne y_j$ then $x_j \le y_j$" is unclear to me.  My interpretation is that if there is some index $i$ such that $x_i \ne y_i$, let $j$ be the smallest $i$.  If $x_j \le y_j$ (or $x_j \lt y_j$), then $\sigma \le_L \tau$.  For example $(011001) \le_L (0101010)$.  But if such a $j$ does not exist, then that half of the condition is false. So $(100) \le_L (1001)$ only because $(1001)$ extends $(100)$.
2. Is there a succinct way to prove the asymmetric and the transitive axiom in the definition of partial order?  I examined case by case.  Assuming that my understanding in question $1.$ is correct, I think I got it.  The following shows that the asymmetric axiom holds:

> Let $\sigma \le_L \tau \le_L \sigma$.  So, both of the following are true:
>   1.  $\tau$ extends $\sigma$ or if there exists a $j$, the smallest index such that $x_j \ne y_j$, then $x_j \le y_j$. 
>   2.  $\sigma$ extends $\tau$ or if there exists a $k$, the smallest index such that $x_k \ne y_k$, then $y_k \le x_k$. 
>   Start with the first scenario in statement $1$.  Suppose that $\tau$ extends $\sigma$.  Then $\sigma = (x_1 x_2 ... x_n)$, $\tau = (y_1 y_2 ... y_m)$ with $n \le m$ and $x_i = y_i$ for all $i = 1 ... n$.  If $\sigma$ extends $\tau$, then $\sigma = \tau$.  On the other hand, if there exists a $j$, the smallest index such that $x_j \ne y_j$ with $y_j \le x_j$, we reach a contradiction.  It is because such a j must be smaller or equal to n, contradicting the premise that $x_i = y_i$ for all $i = 1 ... n$.  So such a scenario cannot happen. 
>   Proceed with the second scenario in statement $1$.  Suppose that there exists a $j$, the smallest index such that $x_j \ne y_j$, then $x_j \le y_j$.  If $\sigma$ extends $\tau$, then again, we'll have a contradiction, because extension requires that $x_i = y_i$ for all $i = 1 ... $min($n,m$).  On the other hand, suppose that there exists a $k$, the smallest index such that $x_k \ne y_k$, then $y_k \le x_k$.  Then $j = k$ with $x_j \le y_j, y_j \le x_j$.  Since we are given that $X$ is a partially order under $\le$, $x_j = y_j$, which produces another contradiction.

Comment: it examines first elements and compare the last. as dictionaries!
(answer for 1st question you just asked.)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: If that's the case, I need to modify my proof slightly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your understanding of the part that was unclear to you is correct. Let $D=\{i:x_i\ne y_i\}$. If $D\ne\varnothing$, let $j=\min D$; then $\sigma\le_L\tau$ iff $x_j\le y_j$. If $D=\varnothing$, then $\sigma\le_L\tau$ iff $\tau$ extends $\sigma$. However, your first example is wrong: $(0101010)\le_L(011001)$, since the first position in which the sequences differ is the third, where $0\le 1$.
2. Your argument for antisymmetry is correct, but it can be shortened a bit. Suppose that $\sigma\le_L\tau\le_L\sigma$, where $\sigma=(x_1\dots x_n)$ and $\tau=(y_1\dots y_m)$. Let $D=\{k:x_k\ne y_k\}$. If $D\ne\varnothing$, let $j=\min D$. Since $\sigma\le_L\tau$, we must have $x_j\le y_j$, and since $\tau\le_L\sigma$, we have $y_j\le x_j$. Thus, $x_j= y_j$, contradicting the choice of $j$. Thus, $D=\varnothing$. But then $\tau$ extends $\sigma$ and $\sigma$ extends $\tau$, so $n\le m\le n$ and hence $n=m$ and $\sigma=\tau$, as desired.

You can prove transitivity similarly. Suppose that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are as above and $\rho=(z_1\dots z_r)$, and that $\sigma\le_L\tau\le_L\rho$. Let $D=\{i:x_i\ne y_i\}$ and $E=\{i:y_i\ne z_i\}$. If $D=\varnothing$, then $\tau$ extends $\sigma$. If, moreover, $E=\varnothing$, then $\rho$ extends $\tau$ and hence $\sigma$, and $\sigma\le_L\rho$. If, on the other hand, $E\ne\varnothing$ and $k=\min E$, then either $m<k$ and $\rho$ extends $\sigma$, or $k\le m$ and $x_k=y_k\le z_k$; in either case $\sigma\le_L\rho$.

To finish it off, suppose that $D\ne\varnothing$, let $j=\min D$, and consider the two possibilities $E=\varnothing$ and $E\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Ok, TY sir ....

Comment: @Andy: You’re welcome.